# Remove random row from dataframe if odd number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I am hoping to randomly remove a row from my data frame when there are an odd number of rows in the data. To do this, I've attempted this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(value 1:100) # Creating data frame

df <- 
case_when(
nrow(df) %% 2 == 0 ~ df, # If even # of rows, keep df as is
                nrow(df) %% 2 != 0 ~ df[-sample(x = nrow(df), size = 1),] # If odd number of rows, randomly sample one row and remove it from df
)
```

I receive

> Error: Can't use NA as column index with `[` at position 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `slice` with `if/else` condition instead of `case_when` as `ifelse/case_when` requires all arguments to be of same length.  According to `?case_when`

> Both LHS and RHS may have the same length of either 1 or n. The value of n must be consistent across all cases. The case of n == 0 is treated as a variant of n != 1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  slice(if(n() %% 2 != 0) -sample(row_number(), 1) else row_number() )
```

Comment: `ifelse` does work, so I do not get why `case_when` don't

Comment: @denis have you checked the output from `ifelse`

Comment: @denis `case_when` or `if_else` also checks the type for all the cases and it throws error if there is any change besides the length issue

Comment: @akrun what does `else row_number()` accomplish? I see it is necessary — but not entirely sure what it does.

Comment: @JonathanCloughesy `slice` requires numeric index and `row_number` gives that index to return all the rows if the condition is not satisfied.  In the `if` conditionit is removing a single row based on sampling

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if`:

```r
df <- if(nrow(df) %% 2 != 0) df[-sample(x = nrow(df), size = 1),]
```